# Sonarqube 5.6 database copy fails (Exception sending context initialized event to listener...)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sonarqube

I need to move a Sonarqube 5.6 installation from one server to another.
The new server will also run with a new database so my plan is to copy
the old data to the new database and then start the new Sonarqube instance
against the new database containing the copied data.

Both new and old are Sonarqube 5.6 with Oracle. The old database is
Oracle 11g and the new will be Oracle 12c, but I am using the Oracle
Express 11g and another local Sonarqube 5.6 installation in order to test the procedure.

I proceed as follows:

(1) Export old database with SQL Developer as DDL (insert format)

(2) Make some small changes to resulting sql:

- Tablespace name is hard-coded and different in target database so adapt
- clause "SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED" not supported in target database, so I simply deleted it

(3) Import sql to new target database

(4) Start new Sonarqube instance connecting to new database

After this unfortunately the Sonarqube server ends and in the logs I see the error/exception:

**Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener**

(full text below).

Further tests:
If I start the new Sonarqube instance against the new database with no imported data
fresh tables are created and all is well. After doing that I can also export the new database,
drop and recreate the new sonarqube database user, and re-import the data from the new environment,
also works fine.
That is to say the new installation in stand-alone mode works fine, the export/import also works
fine (at least with minimal data and exported from the same environment / database).
The problem therefore seems to be caused by something in the data I am importing from the old
Sonarqube installation.
I have also tried after the import rebuilding all indexes (no change), and deleting all rows
from all tables (sonarqube then tries to create new tables and runs into an error because
table projects alreads exists).

One thing that does occur to me is that the old installation has many plugins. I have tried
to get the new installation to the same state but it is not totally identical, there are a few
version differences and the old installation had some licenced plugins (Swift and Objective C)
that I do not have for my local test installation. There are also a few error messages in the log
to that effect, but these don't seem to be the critical problem.

**2017.01.21 00:07:53 ERROR web[cpp] No license for cpp

2017.01.21 00:07:53 ERROR web[objc] No license for objc**

I have also tried deleting the logs, data, temp directories in Sonarqube before starting the
new server against the new database.
I have of course searched for this error message but it seems to mostly occur when migrating
from one Sonar version to another which is not the case here.

Does anyone have any thoughts?
Should this procedure theoretically work or have I missed something?

Many thanks for any ideas!

```
2017.01.21 00:08:29 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2017.01.21 00:08:29 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:82) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:88) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:201) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_65]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:303) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(IOUtils.java:246) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.sonar.db.source.FileSourceDto.decodeTestData(FileSourceDto.java:169) ~[sonar-db-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestResultSetIterator.read(TestResultSetIterator.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestResultSetIterator.read(TestResultSetIterator.java:60) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.ResultSetIterator.next(ResultSetIterator.java:82) ~[sonar-db-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:93) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$2.index(BaseIndexer.java:91) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$1.run(BaseIndexer.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        ... 4 common frames omitted
2017.01.21 00:08:29 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2017.01.21 00:08:29 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017.01.21 00:08:29 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
 java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
 com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:860)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.01.21 00:08:29 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Progress[BulkIndexer[tests]]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2017.01.21 00:08:29 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.01.21 00:08:29 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2017.01.21 00:08:29 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.01.21 00:08:29 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not start
        at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
2017.01.21 00:08:29 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.01.21 00:08:30 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.01.21 00:08:30 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2017.01.21 00:08:30 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2017.01.21 00:08:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2017.01.21 00:08:31 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2017.01.21 00:08:31 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1484953654097] stopping ...
```

Comment: Why no use the Oracle [upgrade](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/upgrading-to-12c#supported-upgrade-paths) documentation?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, yes fair point - with the prod install I will be going 11g -> 12c so that would make sense, however the test I describe above is to my Express database which is also 11g so there should be no Oracle upgrade necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Server fails to start if target database is not an exact copy of the source database. You should double-check that all tables and sequences have exactly the same content, values of primary keys included. A strategy is to start a fresh install on the target db so that SonarQube creates the schema. Then a data backup can be restored.

Comment: Note also that the DB Copy tool can help you. It is part of the SonarQube Enterprise Edition: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+DB+Copy+Tool

Comment: Thanks, is your idea then to start with an empty database and let Sonarqube create a new one initially, and then somehow import the exported data manually into the existing tables? Sonarqube seems to have no database backup/restore facility of it's own.

Unfortunately the Sonar DB Copy Tool only comes with the Enterprise Edition of Sonar Source which we don't have and costs $50 000.

Answer (score 0):

OK working now so just a quick update maybe it will help others... It seems it is necessary to let the new sonar instance initialise the new database and then to do a "hard" copy by which I mean in the SQl Developer the options copy objects, replace existing target objects, truncate target data before copy.

I couldn't quite figure this out because the initial startup must do something that causes the error I was getting to go away, so something must be left of it in the database even after the hard copy. Soft copy not replacing objects allowed Sonar to start but with problems - e.g. key violations when creating users or groups. The latter could be fixed by rebuilding indexes and/or or dropping and reactivating constraints, the former was the result of differing initial values of sequences used to set user-id. But the hard copy circumvented all these problems, so that is the route I would recommend. I also deleted the directories data, temp, logs from SONAR_HOME, I'm not 100% sure if this is necessary.